# Why I can't import a plugin in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I want to import QtPositioning 5.2 to my project and create a map.
I can import this but when I want to use a type, for example "map" i can't. In design I don't see more options for QtPositioning I see only this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFlBe.jpg

What and where I have to add to the project?

Comment: Getting Started: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtpositioning-index.html 
Have you tried it?

Comment: `import QtPositioning 5.5`

`import QtLocation 5.6`

The second one gives you `Map`.

Comment: Nothing. Still I don't have a 'map'.Both my plugins still are not loaded

Comment: I have the plugin loaded but I cannot see the type in the designer. I cannot say if it's a bug or a missing feature of the designer. Qt Creator 4.2 beta is out. I would give it a try to test. In any case remember that `QtLocation` contains the mapping feature. `QtPositioning ` gives the gps values used in the former. Sorry but I cannot help more than that. :(